# Why do I feel internal tremors/shaking while meditation?

Tags: yoga, meditation, sadhana, explanation

I'm new to this site. Apologies in advance if I made any mistake. Please read the details.

I've recently started meditation. I do it every night before sleeping. But after a few minutes of starting meditation, I felt internal tremors (not violent shaking, but tremors like what you'd feel in an earthquake). Also, one thing to note is that I am not shaking physically. I feel this is happening internally. This has been happening right from the 1st day of my medication. And the tremors’ intensity has been increasing.

I tried searching online about this, but I only found scenarios where the physical body shakes uncontrollably. Based on what I've read, it's because of kundalini raising.

But as I mentioned, in my case, my physical body is not moving/shaking, it's something within me that is shaking. So I don't think it's kundalini. Plus, I just started a few weeks ago, so it cannot be this quick.

In short, I want to ask:

**1. What is this feeling of internal shaking/tremors? What does it mean and what exactly is shaking within me? Is this really happening? Or should I just conclude that I'm probably hallucinating and have lost my mind and stop meditation?**

**2. Is there any mention of such experience anywhere in the scriptures?**

And thank you for your answers/comments.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because (i) it is not about Hinduism and (ii) personal advice questions are off-topic in any case.

Comment: It is a physical reaction that many starting to meditation experience. It will pass in time. It is NOT the kundalini rising. Seek your guru.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda thank you for making me realize that I'm not dreaming and this happens to others too. And you are right, I must seek a guru. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The tremors and shaking experiences might be a sign of internally dormant impurities.

Swami Sivananda of the Divine Life Society observes in his book [SPIRITUAL TREASURE](https://www.dlshq.org/books/spiritual-treasure/)
that -

> #### Chapter Nine - THE INNER PATH OF MEDITATION
>
> 17. **Despair, pain, tremor and hard breathing are obstacles in meditation.**
> 18. If you feel sleepy and fidgety when you pray and meditate, **know that the mind is impure and needs immediate attendance.**
> 19. During meditation, the external objects will be shut out; **but sometimes, the Samskaras that are lying dormant in the subconscious
>     mind will come out to the surface of the conscious mind and cause
>     distraction**. Gradually they will subside, when you advance in deep
>     meditation.

So the tremors, and bodily shaking are an obstacle, and results from inherent samskaras.

Therefore, to get success in concentration, meditation and the practice of Yoga, you must have tremendous patience, tremendous will and tremendous perseverance. One needs more patience, practice and purity to sail through these obstacles to reach deeper levels of Meditation, [as per](https://www.dlshq.org/download/practical-lessons-in-yoga/) Swami Sivananda.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Vivikta. Are the signs (pain, tremors, etc) mentioned in the book external/physical or internal? I do plan and hope to keep up my practice of medication and yoga for a long time. Hope these tremors stop one day and I make some progress in this lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I'm only suggesting what I know, please consult a meditation guru like go to vipassana teaching and they will tell you to do properly.

First of all what kind of meditation are you doing? How long?

There are 8 steps in yoga,

Yama, Niyama, Asana, Pranayama, Prathyahara, Dhyana, Dharana and Samadhi. You are directly jumping to Dhyana. That's why maybe you are getting these.

Now first you should be moral and good minded, doing good things and happy. And you must be able to sit in a place comfortably.

You must strengten the mind and nerves. So make sure you don't eat tamasic foods and make sure you fast twice a month on Ekadashis so your body becomes pure. Also try to keep your colon clean by using triphala or aloe vera juice at night and neem and turmeric with lukewarm water and honey early morning. This will purify your blood, and strengthen nerves. Make sure you are well fed with vitamins especially B-complex and not suffer from B12 defeciency. If possible eat only twice daily, with 8 hour gap amd don't eat anything in between except water. Make sure you are not malnourished. Dont take this on your own, talk to Ayurveda doctor.

See here

https://youtu.be/LgvgQgtng0U
https://youtu.be/VPZx6Dffu4Q
https://youtu.be/xfZCFME4Gsw
https://youtu.be/KAz7G6wgCeQ

To purify nerves you may need to do Nadishodana pranayama for atleast 7 minutes twice daily before meditating.

See here https://youtu.be/q5m6tMjcF8k

And chant Aaa 7 times, Ooo 7 times and Mmm 7 times.

See here https://youtu.be/HCrls7zpIic

Only after you have done this it is good to meditate. What kind of meditation are you doing? Here is a simple meditation

https://youtu.be/C_xsXnRd_uc

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering Hari Kumar. I will surely go thorugh your suggestions. I meditate for 20 minutes daily. Initially started with 10 minutes but increased it gradually. I meditate to 'Om Namah Shivay' chanting being played on my headphone at low volume.

Comment: I would humbly suggest to you to learn meditation from someone instead of doing the technique on your own. What you are doing is japa not dhyana.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. Even others have suggested me to seek a guru. Will do as uou say. Thank you.